# Power BI reply URL does not match reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

There are many similar questions asked in Stack Overflow but so far as I'm aware, none provide the information that solves this issue.

#### Goal

Anyone in my organization (but not outside of it) must be able to view a Power BI report. Not all users in my organization have Power BI Pro accounts, so sharing the report in SharePoint is not an option, as I understand it.

#### Background

In past years I embedded a Power BI report in an Azure web app using a Power BI workspace collection and secured it with Azure Active Directory. This worked fine. Recently Microsoft retired Power BI workspace collections. I need to find another way to embed the report in an Azure web app.

#### Failed attempts

I tried using Microsoft's onboarding/migration tool but it was too confusing. (I am not a professional developer.) Sample Power BI and Azure code provided by Microsoft on GitHub are also confusing to me.

An [Angular solution on Medium](https://medium.com/@ramandeep.singh.1983/power-bi-overview-and-angular-embedding-how-to-f73390f4a399) successfully walked me through the steps to accomplish my goal, but placed the responsibility of creating a solution that can fetch access tokens on the reader, a skill I don't have.

A [Visual Studio solution in GitHub](https://github.com/devkeydet/Embed-Power-BI) embeds a report in an Azure web app if the following are provided:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    "ClientId": "redacted",
    "ClientSecret": "redacted",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Resource": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
    "EmbedUrlBase": "https://app.powerbi.com/*"
```

#### Status

I collected the `ClientId` from Azure > Azure Active Directory > Application ID.

I collected the `ClientSecret` from Azure > Azure Active Directory > Keys > added key called "secret", saved, and copied the value.

Reply URLs I've tried (based on suggestions on the web) include:

- https://website.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
- https://app.powerbi.com/embedsetup/SignInRedirect (which I believe was added when I attempted to use the onboarding/migration tool)
- http://localhost/* (http://localhost:44341/* works when built locally)

In addition, I have a `Report ID`, `Workspace ID`, `Group ID` from the onboarding/migration tool.

#### Problem

I continue to encounter the `AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application` error. (No reply URL is specified in the error message.)

#### Question

How do I successfully provide a reply URL and callback path? An answer that would be helpful would direct me how to find exactly what to type in.

I can provide additional information if needed. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no value specified for the Reply URL in your config. This needs to be there as well. In your App Registration and in your config you need to list the same URL as your Reply URL. This is where you want the user to be directed after he or she has signed in. Try listing your main homepage URL (https://hccanalytics.azurewebsites.net/) in both.

See my [blog post](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b) and video to see if this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your help Marilee Turscak!